# embedding fonts in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, font-face

I am trying to embed some fonts via a CSS file for my asp.net website but without success.

Here is the code for the CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  src: url('SEGOEUI.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Segoe WP;
  src: url('SEGOEWP.ttf');
}
body  
{
    background: Black;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family:'Segoe WP';
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: black;
}
```

And the CSS file and fonts are all within the Styles folder which is in the root of the site.
Running IE10 and Win 7.

What am I missing in getting this to work?

UPDATE: I have converted the fonts to EOT and called them like this:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      src: url('SEGOEUI.eot');
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Segoe WP';
      src: url('SEGOEWP.eot');
    }
```

But still nothing.

Comment: Open Sans is packaged on Google Fonts and so is trivial to include/implement correctly, its very close to Segoe and its licensed for use (unlike Segoe)

Comment: @sd_dracula What if you use font-family: 'SegoeUI';? Spaces and dashes in name may not play nice. Also, are you using bundling? Sometimes that can break the path to the font source.

Answer (score 0):

TTF doesn't seem to be supported by IE. See  http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp.

> **Internet Explorer 9+**, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support the
>   **WOFF** (Web Open Font Format) font.
>
> Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support fonts of type TTF (True
>   Type Fonts) and OTF (OpenType Fonts).
>
> Internet Explorer also supports EOT (Embedded OpenType) fonts.

Which means WOFF or EOT could be a way to go for you. There are many free online font converters, you can try http://www.font2web.com/ or http://ttf2woff.com/.

Answer (score 0):

In IE you have to specify the real font name, some converter give the font after conversion a generated name by generator witch IE can't handle.
Use this website http://www.font-face-generator.com/ and for fonts with spaced in name use double quotes like

```
font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial;
```

Comment: I am getting some strange behaviour, basically some machines detect the fonts and some don't (usually the Windows 8 ones) I am guessing when it does work it just means that the machine has the fonts pre-installed and it does NOT use the font-face ones